# this page say the value inputted by user in the textbox section

Tags: javascript, html

I want the value the user inputted in the textbox section show up in the window.alert

---

```
<input class="textbox" type="text" placeholder="Username" name="" value="">


var name = document.getElementById ("textbox")              
function myFunction() {alert("Welcome back!", name);}
```

This page say: Welcome back! "Username"

---

Comment: `var name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;` ?

Answer (score 0):

The `value` property is what you need

```
var name = document.getElementById("textbox").value

function myFunction() {
  alert("Welcome back!", name)
}

myFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `value` of the text box:

```
var name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistake:

`document.getElementById("textbox")` only return DOM object.

You did not map `function` to any `event`, i assigned to `blur event`, you can choose other event.

You can change to this demo:

```js
function myFunction(e) {
var name = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
  alert("Welcome back! " + name);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="textbox" onblur= "myFunction()" />
```